# How to set correctly near/far clipping in an ortographic projection matrix?

Tags: opengl-es, matrix, three.js, webgl, projection

I want to make the following projection:

```
x' = 2*x - z
y' = -2*y - z
z' = -z
```

I've came up with this matrix:

```
2,  0,  0,  0,
0,  -2, 0,  0,
0,  0,  -1, 0,
0,  0,  0,  screen_width
```

It works mostly as expected, except:

1. It gets deformed in non perfectly square screens.
2. It makes a near/far clipping which removes some objects from the screen. I don't want that.

So, the question boils down to: how do I set the near/far FOV on this Matrix and how do I update it to take account of not only the screen width, but the width/height ratio?

Note: the software in question uses Three.js, but I guess it uses the same convention as OpenGL thus I've tagged it as so.

Answer (score 1):

If you view the [glOrtho()](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glOrtho.xml) page in firefox (chrome *still* doesn't support MathML) it gives the equation it uses for an orthographic matrix.

Getting the Z and W rows right is important for the near/far planes and non-linear depth. If you're getting good results with the (2, -2) scaling, just replace the last two rows with the glOrtho ones and you should be set. Make sure not to choose near/far values too far apart or the depth values start intersecting and you get z-fighting.

Answer (score 0):

[Wikipedia has a good reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthographic_projection_%28geometry%29) on orthographic projections. From that:

[image: img]

You could write a function to generate this matrix given the far/near/right/left/top/bottom

Comment: This does not make any sense. I'm using those slots to determine how much each axis affects the projection. This formula does not provide the information I need.